# Coming from iOS to OS X - where do I put my code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, macos, cocoa

I'm an iOS developer just starting to develop for OS X. In iOS, I always follow the MVC pattern, and put appropriate code in UIViewController subclasses. The App Delegate simply initializes the main view controller, and that's it. After that the view controllers handle all logic.

But in OS X, I seem to put everything in the app delegate. My app delegate class is now about 300 lines long and I am wondering how I can follow the same pattern I did in iOS. There are no view controllers!

What I mean is, what is the common accepted way to organize code for Mac Application?

Comment: Do you mean to say "there's no view controllers"?

Comment: However, there are view controllers on Mac OS X: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: What I mean is, what is the common accepted way to organize code for Mac Application?

Comment: The major patterns for application/UI code architecture are identical between iOS and OS X. See Apple's [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html).

Comment: It also to some degree depends on whether your app is `NSDocument` based or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own controller classes, and put an instantiation of these controller classes between the app delegate or model objects, and your view objects.  Just because there is no pre-built view controller class, does not mean that you can't make your own similar partition, by creating custom controller classes of your own, as needed.